# When is the subobject functor conservative?

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with pullbacks, then the functor $Sub(-):\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Pos}$ takes an object to its poset of subobjects, and a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces a morphism $f^{-1}: Sub(Y) \rightarrow Sub(X)$. When does this this functor reflect isomorphisms? For example, if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets this is the case.

Comment: It seems that this isn't actually true in a topos, as a comment of Arnaud D on my deleted answer pointed out: the topos of $G$-sets is a counterexample for any nontrivial $G$.

Comment: Yes that is a mistake, thanks Arnaud for pointing this out. Will edit the question.

Comment: I haven't seen that deleted answer, but maybe it's worth pointing out that this does hold in any topos, provided we mean by $\mathrm{Sub}(X)$ not the *set* of subobjects, but the *object* of subobjects. This is because the proof in the case of the category of sets is constructive and can hence be repeated in the internal language of the given topos.